# C:#define inside function body

Tags: c

```
# define a 10
main()
{
#define a 50
printf("%d",a);
}
```

The output is coming 50. Why is it happening so? Shouldn't the output come 10?

Comment: didn't you get the `warning: "a" redefined` for your program?

Comment: Better to put a `#undef a` before redefinition

Comment: By the way #define does not apply to a function body, as in the accepted answer it is top to bottom. For this reason it is good style to always put #define at the very top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilation happens from top to bottom. so value of a is replaced by 50 when it enters into main function.

Here the local has precedence than global